# passing arguments with multiple inheritens in python

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I am new to python and have some problem with passing object arguments
i have a file with class Graph

```
class Graph:
   def __init__(self,Name):
      self.Name = Name
      self.Nodes = {}
      self.Edges = {}
   def addEdgeAndNodes(self,sourceName,targetName): ''' code'''
   def getEdgesCount(self):'''code '''
   def getNodesCount(self):''' code '''
#some more code
```

and on other file UpdateGraph class

```
import Graph
class UpdateGraph(Graph.Graph):
      def __init__(self,Name):
          super().__init__(Name)
      def addUpdateEdgeAndNodes(self,sourceName,targetName,sourceType,targetType,edgeType):
#some more code
```

and in GraphBuilder file :

```
from Graph import Graph
from UpdateGraph import UpdateGraph
class GraphDFS:
    def __init__(self,graph):
        self.Graph = graph
        self.dfsRes = {}

    def dfs(self):
         #some code
         print("-->"+self.Graph.getNodesCount())

#some code

class GraphBuilder:
      def __init__(self):
          self.Build()

     def Build(self):
          self.Graph = UpdateGraph(self.name)

def main():
    Graph = GraphBuilder(name)
    dfs = GraphDFS(Graph)
     dfs.dfs()

main()
```

when I  am trying to run the code it raises an error:
AttributeError: 'GraphBuilder' object has no attribute 'getNodesCount'
at line print("-->"+self.Graph.getNodesCount())

graph is a updateGraph type
how can I pass this varible and it will be recognized by Graph Builder functions

Comment: Clearly, `graph` is an instance of `GraphBuilder`, not `UpdateGraph` object, so two questions: what is `GraphBuilder`, and how to you set the value of `graph`?

Comment: Graph Builder just tacking data from text file and building a graph

Comment: show the code where you construct `graph` object

Comment: the grapg varible : graph = UpdateGraph(name)

Comment: Update your question with code where you define `graph`

Comment: i edited the code I hope its understandble

Comment: Graph is a class and you have self.Graph in GraphBuilder and Graph as variable in main(). Why in this world you have to make this so confusing like you are running out of the name of the variable to use?

Comment: `self.name` is not defined in any code you posted. Please post the relevant code if you wish us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    Graph = GraphBuilder(name)
    dfs = GraphDFS(Graph)
    dfs.dfs()
```

You are passing the object of `GraphBuilder` to `GraphDFS`, `self.Graph` is an instance of `GraphBuilder` and you are calling `getNodesCount` on this object, this object doesn't contain such method.

```
from Graph import Graph
from UpdateGraph import UpdateGraph
class GraphDFS:
    def __init__(self,graph):
        self.Graph = graph
        self.dfsRes = {}

    def dfs(self):
         #some code
         print("-->"+self.Graph.getNodesCount())

#some code

class GraphBuilder:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def Build(self):
        self.Graph = UpdateGraph(self.name)

def main():
    name = "" # define the name variable
    Graph = GraphBuilder(name)
    Graph.Build()
    dfs = GraphDFS(Graph.Graph)
    dfs.dfs()

main()
```

Put the above code in `GrapthBuilder` file, this should work fine